# How to create view to read from two collections in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Started with mongoDB syntax and use in project. 
I am looking for a solution where I can combine more than two collections with couple of condition to create a view.

Here is my collection **Range**

```
 /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
        "range" : {
            "start" : "00" 
        },  
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "01",
                "name" : "FirstProduct",
                "type" : "First Type"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "02",
                "name" : "Second Product",
                "type" : "Second Type"
            },
            {
                "id" : "03",
                "name" : "Third Product",
                "type" : "Third Type"
            },
        ]
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
        "range" : {
            "start" : "100",
        },  
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "01",
                "name" : "First Product",
                "type" : "First Type"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "02",
                "name" : "Second Product",
                "type" : "Second Type"
            }
        ]
    }

   /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
        "range" : {
            "start" : "500",
        },  
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "01",
                "name" : "First Product",
                "type" : "First Type"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "02",
                "name" : "Second Product",
                "type" : "Second Type"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Second Collection. **Stock**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "range" : {
        "start" : "00"
    },
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "01",
            "expired" : false,
            "returned" : false
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "02",
            "expired" : false,
            "returned" : false
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("02"),
    "range" : {
        "start" : "100"
    },
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "01",
            "expired" : true,
            "returned" : true
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "02",
            "expired" : true,
            "returned" : true
        }
        {
            "id" : "03",
            "expired" : true,
            "returned" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Now want to have a view with combine result from above two collection above.

```
For each range document in Range collections

    if Range.range.start = Stock.range.start 

        if Range.products.id = Stock.products.id

          copy "expired" and "returned" field from Stock for that product and 
          add to Range.product

        end if  

    end if 

    Return Range
```

So final result will something like below.

```
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
        "range" : {
            "start" : "00" 
        },  
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "01",
                "name" : "FirstProduct",
                "type" : "First Type"
                "expired" : false,
                "returned" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "02",
                "name" : "Second Product",
                "type" : "Second Type"
                "expired" : false,
                "returned" : false
            } 
        ]
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
        "range" : {
            "start" : "100",
        },  
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "01",
                "name" : "First Product",
                "type" : "First Type",
                "expired" : true,
                "returned" : true
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "02",
                "name" : "Second Product",
                "type" : "Second Type",
                "expired" : true,
                "returned" : true
            }
        ]
    }


   /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
        "range" : {
            "start" : "500",
        },  
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "01",
                "name" : "First Product",
                "type" : "First Type"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "02",
                "name" : "Second Product",
                "type" : "Second Type"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I started with [aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) stages with fail to get right queries.
if anyone can help with right syntax and proper aggregate function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to merge the data from both collections but then you have to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to be able to match corresponding documents by `product.id`. In the last step you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get back an array:

```
db.Range.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Stock",
            localField: "range.start",
            foreignField: "range.start",
            as: "stock"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$stock"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$products"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$stock.products"
    },
    {
        $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$products.id", "$stock.products.id" ] } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            "range": { $first: "$range" },
            products: {
                $push: {
                    id: "$products.id",
                    name: "$products.name",
                    type: "$products.type",
                    expired: "$stock.products.expired",
                    returned: "$stock.products.returned"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: Alternative solution which operates directly on arrays using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) below. The drawback is that the code is less readable but the good part is that it should return documents when there's no match and you should get better performance using this approach

```
db.Range.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Stock",
            localField: "range.start",
            foreignField: "range.start",
            as: "stock"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$stock"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            products: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$products",
                    as: "p",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                stockItem: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                        { $filter: { input: "$stock.products", cond: { $eq: [ "$$p.id", "$$this.id" ] } } }, 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $cond: [
                                    { $eq: [ "$$stockItem", undefined ] },
                                    "$$p",
                                    {
                                        id: "$$p.id",
                                        name: "$$p.name",
                                        type: "$$p.type",
                                        expired: "$$stockItem.expired",
                                        returned: "$$stockItem.returned",
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            stock: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I have never used this feature so I'm not sure about the cost benefits, but it looks like a pipeline like above can be used to create a `view`, on which find() queries can be run. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/

Comment: @Bajal yes, this can be passed as a `pipeline` parameter

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to get all the fields value from input document instead of getting it one by on like  "range": { $first: "$range" }.  As in example only field is there but with real problem many fields are there. So it will all field of input document + pushed fields.

Comment: @SanjayJain you can use this $first for all of them. As they come from the same document (grouping by _id) they will all have the same value

Comment: Thanks, Also product entries only in case of $eq: [ "$products.id", "$stock.products.id" ]  but if it not matching then I need products entry with out expire and return element.

Comment: @SanjayJain modifed my answer and added alternative approach, you can try it out